# ACL Role Resource Default

Tags: admin, adminhtml, acl, permissions

Let's say we add some new resources to the ACL like so:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <catalog>
                    <children>
                        <search>
                            <children>
                                <import translate="title">
                                    <title>Import</title>
                                </import>
                                <export translate="title">
                                    <title>Export</title>
                                </export>
                            </children>
                        </search>
                    </children>
                </catalog>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

We then add the following around a button that appears in the SearchTerm grid:

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('catalog/search/import')) {
    $this->_addButton('import', array(
        'label'   => 'Import Search Terms',
        'onclick' => "setLocation('".$this->getUrl('*/*/import')."')"
    ));
}
```

If I then log in as a non-admin user, I would really have thought that the expected behavior would be no button visible, since I haven't explicitly given the users role the resource. As it turns out though, the default return value of `isAllowed` appears to be true. To compound matters, when you go and view the resources for that role, the checkbox will not appear ticked.

I can resolve the 'issue' by clicking through each role and clicking save, but this is a PITA to do especially across live / stage / dev environments. Is there any easy way to auto deny this resource from each role via code? I don't mind adding a migration script if required. I had a quick look at what happens in the same action. Presumably, I could do this by loading all roles, looping through them and performing similar logic to `Mage_Admin_Model_Resource_Rules::saveRel` inserting the rows into the table. But this code appears to assume that all resources are posted, which would mean in order to invoke it directly I'd need to work out what format I need to pass it data in and possibly load existing resource too.

Comment: Not sure you are using 'isAllowed' correctly - shouldn't it be this? `$session->isAllowed($session->getData('acl')->get('catalog/search/import')->getResourceId())`

Comment: Seems like a bug to me

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to recreate the problem on 1.13.1.0.  I used your exact code except I used it to change title of the page conditionally.  I first tested this with a user logged in with all permissions and the isAllowed method returned true.  I then created another role which did not have this checkbox selected but had all other boxes selected and then I logged out and logged back in with a user attached to this new role and isAllowed was returning false.  You might try logging out and logging back in.  If this still is not working, try clearing out your cache and sessions and logging back in.

Answer (score 0):

The default value in `Mage_Admin_Model_Session` is actually `false` (wouldn't make sense otherwise):

```
public function isAllowed($resource, $privilege = null)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $acl = $this->getAcl();

    if ($user && $acl) {
        if (!preg_match('/^admin/', $resource)) {
            $resource = 'admin/' . $resource;
        }

        try {
            return $acl->isAllowed($user->getAclRole(), $resource, $privilege);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            try {
                if (!$acl->has($resource)) {
                    return $acl->isAllowed($user->getAclRole(), null, $privilege);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) { }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

<del>But what might have happened is, that the roles had permissions set for `catalog`, i.e. you did not select all single children but the catalog checkbox itself. Then it is saved as one permission that counts for all children (`catalog/*`), even if they are added later.</del>

Sorry, that was not true. Every permission is saved separately *additional* to the parent.

Comment: Where is the logic that allows one permission to account for all children?

Comment: I checked again and couldn't find it, looks like this parent resources only exist so that you can check for `isAllowed('catalog')` - it does not implicitly allow access to all children. Sorry for the misinformation!